# Proving that two groups are (or aren't) isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

My task it to say whether two groups $\mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{18} \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ and  $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{36} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are isomorphic

Now, I know that $4\cdot 18 \cdot 15 = 3 \cdot 36 \cdot 10$ so the two groups are the same size. However, I also know that if you have a group $|G| =n=p_{1}^{n_1}p_{2}^{n_2}...p_{\alpha }^{n_\alpha}$ that there are $n_1 \cdot n_2 \cdot ... n_\alpha$ abelian groups up to isomorphism. I also know that the two groups I have been given are different ways of decomposing $1080$ (the order of the group). Is this enough to prove the two groups are not isomorphic? Or, should I be looking for an element in one of the groups that does not have a "counterpart" in the other group?

Comment: Your claim about the number of abelian groups of given order is incorrect; there are way more than that. What do you know about the structure of finite abelian groups in general?

Comment: Have you proved that $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ if and only if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ for any $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$? This allows you to "break down" the structure into factors as small as possible (primary decomposition) or combine them into factors as big as possible (invariant factors), either of which uniquely [identifies](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fundamental_theorem_of_finitely_generated_abelian_groups#/Classification) the finite(ly generated) abelian group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just turning the comment of Sammy Black into an answer: write $C_n = \mathbb{Z}_n$ and observe:
$$ C_4 \times C_{18} \times C_{15} \cong C_4 \times C_2 \times C_9 \times C_3 \times C_5$$
as well as
$$C_3 \times C_{36} \times C_{10} \cong C_3 \times C_4 \times C_9 \times C_2 \times C_5$$
both by the chinese remainder thmeorem.